# terminology for a kind of two-sided module over a monoid

Tags: ct.category-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

If $M$ is a monoid object in a pointed category $\mathcal{C}$, then a right $M$-module is an object $X$ equipped with a morphism $\alpha: X\times M\to X$ that satisfies the usual rules.  There are also right modules, and $X$ has both structures, it is a two-sided $M$-module.

Every right $M$-module comes with a coefficient morphism  $M\to X\times M \to X$;  and likewise for right modules.   If $X$ is a two-sided module, then it has a left coefficient morphism $L:M\to X$ and a right coefficient morphism $R: M\to X$.  These need not be equal.

My question:  what is the correct term for the two-sided modules for which $L = R$?

Comment: It might help to explain to non category theorists what is the coefficient morphisms. Should I think of C like pointed sets and the coefficient morphisms multiplies by the base point? Then it seems on the two sided case you want the base point to be central

Comment: Are these the same as bimodules equipped with a bimodule map from M? Like, (BMod_M)_{M/}?